# Are questions about Bible verses (not about Christ) acceptable here?

Tags: discussion

Are general questions about interpretations of Bible verses acceptable here?

For example, I was thinking of asking this question (but I caught myself just in time):

- What are we to understand by the word 'divided' in Gen 10:25?

This verse has nothing to do with Christ or Christianity as a whole, but is requesting an interpretation of a specific Bible verse.

I understand that it probably wouldn't be appropriate for the private beta, but should questions like this be acceptable in the long-run?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

They should be accepted in the long run. Of course there is the question of relevancy; if I were to ask about Matthew 1:13, I should have to explain what there is to interpret and what it matters. As for the private beta, I think we should optimally have high-quality questions of many different types. So rather quality than quantity; I think your question is on-topic, so it's very welcome if you put a little effort into it.

I already did ask [Should Genesis 1:2 be translated "And the earth became without form..."?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/75/should-gen-12-be-translated-and-the-earth-became-without-form) . I thought it makes a relevant, on-topic question. Didn't really think that it even could be off-topic.

Answer (score 6):

This may just be a Catholic interpretation of the bible, but we believe that every book in the Bible points to Christ.

So even if the question doesn't specifically mention Jesus or His Church, there's no reason answer couldn't.

Comment: This is not limited to the Catholic church but the church catholic.  Many (particularly Reformed) Protestants hold strongly to the idea that all of Scripture points to Christ.